# Dropdown javascript block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with javascript dropdown clicking menu.
I need show some content after clicking header of box.

HTML

```
<div id='cookiemenu'>
                <div class='cookiemenu_header' onclick='ShowCookieBox()'>
                    Test
                </div>
                <div id="cookiemenu_dropwdown" class='cookiemenu_content'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis magna sed scelerisque hendrerit.
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #cookiemenu {
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;

}
#cookiemenu div.cookiemenu_header {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #0B3954;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#cookiemenu div.cookiemenu_header:hover, div.cookiemenu_header:target {
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div.cookiemenu_content {
}
.ShowCookieBox {
  display:block;
  border:2px solid #red;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
 function ShowCookieBox() {
    document.getElementById("cookiemenu_dropdown").classList.toggle("ShowCookieBox");
 }
</script>
```

It's not working at all. Can someone tell me why?

And the second question. Is there any chance to change the JS so It could save "status" of box (showed or hidden) in cookies? So user can leave it, close page and on the next visit it stays as he leaved it?

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos.

The id of the div should be `cookiemenu_dropdown` on the div, but it is currently `cookiemenu_dropwdown`.

Also the color is just `red` not `#red`.

```js
function ShowCookieBox() {
 document.getElementById("cookiemenu_dropdown").classList.toggle("ShowCookieBox");
}
```

```css
 #cookiemenu {
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;

}
#cookiemenu div.cookiemenu_header {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #0B3954;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#cookiemenu div.cookiemenu_header:hover, div.cookiemenu_header:target {
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div.cookiemenu_content {
}
.ShowCookieBox {
  display:block;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='cookiemenu'>
  <div class='cookiemenu_header' onclick='ShowCookieBox()'>
    Test
  </div>
  <div id="cookiemenu_dropdown" class='cookiemenu_content'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis magna sed scelerisque hendrerit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad when I've edited this post. In my source code it's right. It's not working at all.

Comment: Make sure you change the `#red` in the CSS too.

Comment: Oh thanks. But when i try to change cookiemenu_content hide (display: none;) and after javascrips use toogle display:block; It's not working. Do you know why? thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS rules to

```
div.cookiemenu_content.ShowCookieBox {
    display: block;
    border:2px solid red;
}
div.cookiemenu_content {
    display: none;
}
```

The `display: block` from `.ShowCookieBox` was being overwritten by `display: none` from the `div.cookiemenu_content` rules when the `ShowCookieBox` class was applied.

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uewswy80/3/)